# KUP-04020: found record longer than buffer size supported error while loading data using DBMS_CLOUD

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

Any ideas about how to specify the readsize to fix the error below while loading a csv file to ADB using DBMS_CLOUD?

```
Error report -
ORA-20000: ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-04020: found record longer than buffer size supported, 10002432, in https://swiftobjectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com/v1/namespace/bucketname/filename.csv (offset=0)
ORA-06512: at "C##CLOUD$SERVICE.DBMS_CLOUD", line 557
ORA-06512: at "C##CLOUD$SERVICE.DBMS_CLOUD", line 1013
ORA-06512: at "C##CLOUD$SERVICE.DBMS_CLOUD", line 1036
ORA-06512: at line 2
20000. 00000 - "%s"
*Cause: The stored procedure 'raise_application_error'
was called which causes this error to be generated.
*Action: Correct the problem as described in the error message or contact
the application administrator or DBA for more information.
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: **YOUR** code that generated that error message; details of the data that was passed into the code; the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following format option to the DBMS_CLOUD.COPY_DATA procedure if the records in your source file are larger than default buffer size which is 10MB.

```
format => json_object('readsize' value '20000000')
```

For more information about format options of DBMS_CLOUD, you can check the following documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/format-options.html#GUID-08C44CDA-7C81-481A-BA0A-F7346473B703

Comment: Please [edit] the answer to include details of where that format option should be applied.